# detect arabic input in Edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, arabic

I want to detect if input string in EditText is arabic or english, How i can do this? i search about it but there is no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way of doing this, what you can do is add all the Arabic "characters" to a Hashset, add a listener to EditText, and every time there's a change to the EditText, check to see if the new entry exist in the HashSet.